# How can I return EnityCollection from virtual ICollection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I use Entity Framework Code First.
I have 2 very similar classes with virtual ICollection Property.
Here is one of them with collection class:

```
public class Name
{
   public int Id{ get; set;}

   [MaxLength(64)]
   [Index(IsUnique = true)]
   [Required]
   public string Value { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<NameVariant> Variants { get; set; }
 }

 public class NameVariant
 {
   public int Id{ get; set;}

   [MaxLength(64)]
   [Index(IsUnique = true)]
   [Required]
   public string Value { get; set; }

   public int ParentId { get; set; }

   public virtual Name Parent { get; set; }
 }
```

I get EntityCollection from Variants in one case and HashSet in another.
What does it depend? How can I get EnityCollection from both class?

Answer (score 4):

The member states that it will return an interface.  You need to code to that interface, and assume that the code can return any type that it wants so long as that type implements the interface, rather than relying on a particular concrete implementation being returned.